# Regex to capture string except last 2 letters in PCRE

Tags: regex, regex-group, pcre

I have a strings test01, abcd02, xyz05 from those strings, I will have last 2 characters are always numbers. From those strings, I want a regex expression to capture test, abcd, xyx. How can I capture it?

Comment: Something like `(test|abcd|xyz)\d\d`. What stopped you from writing this yourself?

Comment: @Luatic i just gave those strings as an example, sorry if i was not clear. I need to capture the word except last 2 letters is my ask here.

Comment: So `(.*)..$` will capture everything before the last 2 characters.

Comment: @Barmar that works, https://regex101.com/r/MF7S5A/1. Thanks

Comment: Obviously it works, it's trivial. What problem were you having coming up with this?

Comment: I need to use strings (without numbers) for further String concatenations.

Answer (score 2):

A few questions:

- Could your string have more or less than 2 digits?
- If it's fixed to two digits, then why not just dropping the 2 last
  chars and not use a regular expression?
- Is it because we have to validate the input? Typically, what
  about "# @123"?

If you have to check that it's ending with digits, then don't
use the solution `(.*)..$` proposed in the comments as `.` matches
any character and you'll get, for example, "Hel" out of "Hello". It
has the same effect as just truncating your string.

I would personally be more precise and also take in consideration
only words, to avoid matching something like "12345" or "!#@123".

I would suggest this:

```
/^(\p{L}+)\d+$/u
```

Explanation:

- The `u` flag at the end is for **u**nicode, so that you can handle
  special chars, such as emojis or other special characters, not
  knowing what is your input text.
- With *PCRE*, you can use
  [unicode character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).
  This can help you match a word character in any language with `\p{L}`,
  which means **L**etter. It's about the same as `\w` but with the
  handling of multiple codepoint sequences.
- If the end of your string must be digits then you can use `\d+`.
  If it really has to be only 2 digits, then replace it by `\d{2}`.

```js
const strings = [
  'test01',  // Ok
  'abcd02',  // Ok
  'test123', // More than 2 digits, perhaps ok also?
  'vidéo05', // Accented chars in the word, ok or not?
  '123456',  // Only digits => should it match? maybe not!
  '####03',  // Not word chars before the digits... hmm, no match.
  'Hello'    // No digits at all... no match.
];

const regex = /^(\p{L}+)\d+$/u;

strings.forEach(string => {
  const match = regex.exec(string);
  if (match) {
    console.log(`Word found in "${string}" is "${match[1]}"`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Does NOT match "${string}"`);
  }
});
```

With PCRE you'll get the same: https://regex101.com/r/bvY3dg/1

Comment: An exceptionally good answer for an exceptionally lazy question. I don't have your tolerance, but this is good stuff - well done.

Comment: @halfer Thanks a lot! Yes, you are totally right, I probably shouldn't have replied to the rather lazy question. He probably even didn't see my answer, haha. I'll be less tolerant in the future, as you say!

Comment: It's actually fine - since you have some upvotes I think the question won't be deleted. But some questions are so terrible that folks will vote to delete, and any good answers will vanish with them.

Comment: It perhaps is not a requirement that any given question author responds to or appreciates an answer, since good ones will be appreciated by future readers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked for me:

```
(.*)..$
```

https://regex101.com/r/MF7S5A/1

Comment: That pattern is too generous - the two dots at the end anchor will match any characters, not just digits.